# Easier way to get just one value from xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

Is there an easier way to get the `InnerText` from just one node in an `xml`?

At the moment I'm using following code to get the value:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(callback); //callback
string txt = xml.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.LastChild.InnerText;
```

I wonder if there is any way to get the value without loading the whole `XmlDocument`. I just need to acces this one node and value.

Thanks in advance!

**Sample XML:** (the `TRACK` node appears up to 80 times, here 13 times)

```
<RESPONSES>
    <RESPONSE STATUS="OK">
        <ALBUM>
            <ID>some_long_id_123456789123456789</ID>
            <ARTIST>some_artist</ARTIST>
            <TITLE>some_album</TITLE>
            <PKG_LANG>ENG</PKG_LANG>
            <DATE>1234</DATE>
            <GENRE NUM="123456" ID="654321">some_string</GENRE>
            <TRACK_COUNT>13</TRACK_COUNT>
            <TRACK>
                <TRACK_NUM>1</TRACK_NUM>
                <ID>some_id_123456789</ID>
                <TITLE>some_title</TITLE>
            </TRACK>
            ...
            <TRACK>
                <TRACK_NUM>13</TRACK_NUM>
                <ID>some_id_123456789_13</ID>
                <TITLE>some_title_13</TITLE>
            </TRACK>
            <URL TYPE="IMAGE" SIZE="MEDIUM" WIDTH="123456" HEIGHT="123456">the_url_i_wanna_access</URL>
        </ALBUM>
    </RESPONSE>
</RESPONSES>
```

Comment: You can use `XmlReader` to read nodes one-by one until you find your desired node.

Comment: For a start, I'd use LINQ to XML rather than `XmlDocument`.  Then I'd create a readable query.  If the XML is huge, you can get performance improvements using lower level APIs like `XmlReader` directly.  You need to give some context - the XML and what you want from it.

Comment: @CharlesMager added sample xml, was editing & shorting it already to fit in here..

Comment: So you're trying to get the `TITLE` of the first `TRACK`?

Comment: @CharlesMager no, `xml.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.LastChild.InnerText` leads to the `URL` tag at the end of the album node, especially the inner text ("the_url_i_wanna_access")

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - though does indicate that queries like this one aren't terribly obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using LINQ to XML could be as simple as this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var url = (string)doc.Descendants("URL").Single();
```

This is a little more readable than the `XmlDocument` API code you have already.

If you're concerned about performance (I'm not sure this XML is big enough to warrant this), you could use `XmlReader` directly to avoid loading all the XML into the DOM just to read one piece of text:

```
string url;

using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "URL")
        {
            url = reader.ReadElementString();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to improve Charles' answer:

`return (string)doc.Descendants().Single(e => string.Equals(e.Name.LocalName, "URL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`
this will continue working if someone uses a namespace definition

Comment: @BerndK ... but there is no namespace in this case?  If there were it's far more advisable to specify the fully qualified name than to just compare the local name (let alone just comparing the local name ignoring the case).